# Reverse Proxy - Can I use one IP for multiple hosts?

Tags: firewall, reverse-proxy, dmz

I would like to setup an internal box that all all external traffic gets forwarded to, and then onto the relevant boxes in-house.

I would like to know the following:

If I have two servers in-house, mail.*domainA*.com and mail.*domainB*.com can a reverse proxy forward the correct request on the same IP based on what was requested? For example, the request for *domainA*.com goes to *servera*.local and *domainB*.com goes to *serverb*.local?

Also, I'd like to build a linux based proxy, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

If these are mail servers and you're talking about incoming email then what you want is a MTA (eg exim, postfix) that accepts email for the domains and forwards it to the correct internal host. This is a basic mailhub setup.

If you're talking about users using imap, pop or smtp (or just web traffic) then have a look at [NginX](http://nginx.org/en/).

Comment: +1 for nginx - I added the link.

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming requests are http protocol, then perhaps Apache virtual hosts in conjunction with mod_proxy ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html ) may do what you want.